# How to solve integrals of the form $\sqrt{ax^4+bx^2+c}$?

Tags: integration

How do you integrate $\sqrt{ax^4+bx^2+c}$? I tried substituting $x^2=t$, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of the elementary functions. You need elliptic integrals.

Comment: This is what the general integral looks like. If only it were as simple as $x^2=t$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E2%2Bc%29

Comment: Thank you. I will search elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these are elementary
$$
\int\sqrt{x^4+2 x^2+1}\;dx = \frac{x^3}{3}+1+C
$$
But in general these are [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) .  For example,
$$
\int\sqrt{-x^4+1}\;dx = \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^4}}{3} +
\frac{2}{3}\;F(x,1) + C
$$
where $F$ is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Thank you. I am reading about them.